# Как работает вложенный map выражении where

Tags: haskell

Я новичок в Haskell и функционально программировании , недавно начал разбирать статью https://eax.me/haskell-parallel/ про многопоточность .
Так вот мне непонятно как работает where в этой функции из статьи :

```
groupedPasswords :: Int -> Int -> CharList -> [[Password]]
groupedPasswords totalLen prefLen charList =
    map (prependPrefix postfixes) prefixes
  where prefixes = replicateM prefLen charList
        postfixes = replicateM restLen charList
        restLen = totalLen - prefLen
        prependPrefix post prefix = map (prefix ++) post
```

Дело в том что здесь с помощью where создана функция prependPrefix с двумя аргументами post  и prefix , но в выражении `map (prependPrefix postfixes) prefixes`
этой функции передается один аргумент postfixes , а где второй аргумент, откуда он его берет , где аргумент под названием prefix ? Я понимаю что здесь два вложенных map и это нужно для распаковки двух вложенных списков и их конкатенации и дальнейшей упаковки в список списков, но опять же map это функция двух аргументов. Как такое может быть?
Функция работает , но как не пойму . Конечный результат и смысл функции  объяснять не нужно. Подскажите пожалуйста знающие люди где я неправильно размышляю .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве формального параметра `post` в `prependPrefix` передается `postfixes`, а второй ее параметр передается `map`ом из списка `prefixes`.

Аналогично, `(+)` - это функция двух параметров, но можно писать `map (+1) [1,2,3]`. Одно слагаемое - `1`, а второе берется `map`ом из списка.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснения , разобрался